# How to do multiple attempts to upload using SFTP protocol?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

In case of file upload fails then how to do multiple attempts while doing SFTP by using JSCH API? 
How to ensure file is uploaded successfully? 
How to create thread-safe file upload utility?

Comment: Please, could you show us [what you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)? A good question should be clear, specific and show some research effort.

Comment: I was trying to create SFTP utility to upload files on MFT server but I could not get much help from the forums. Then I created my own utility. Just to help, I created this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a common static utility method which can be invoked from the external class. This method has a map argument to persist the values of sFTPUser, sFTPHost, sFTPPort, sFTPPwd, destinationLocation and uploadedFileName :

```
public static void doSFTP(Map<String, String> ftpParameters) {

        if (ftpParameters.get("ID_NAME").equals(
                NAPSCommonConstants.MFT_NAPSGPCS_INTF)) {
            // do sftp for NAPS GPCS Interface.
            uploadUsingSFTP(ftpParameters);
        }
    }
```

Use synchronized method to ensure thread safety:

```
private static synchronized void uploadUsingSFTP(
            Map<String, String> ftpPrameterList) {
        new SFTPUtility().uploadFileMFT(ftpPrameterList.get("sFTPUser"),
                ftpPrameterList.get("sFTPHost"), new Integer(ftpPrameterList
                        .get("sFTPPort")), ftpPrameterList.get("sFTPPwd"),
                ftpPrameterList.get("sourceLocation"), ftpPrameterList
                        .get("destinationLocation"), ftpPrameterList
                        .get("uploadedFileName"));
    }
```

Responsible method to upload files using SFTP with 5 attempts:

```
private void uploadFileMFT(String sFTPUser, String sFTPHost, int sFTPPort,
            String sFTPPwd, String sourceLocation, String destinationLocation,
            String uploadedFileName) {

        LOG.info("Inside uploadFileMFT to upload and verify the file.");

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Vector<String> fileList = null;

        /** 5 re-attempt logic to get session */
        int attempts = 0;
        boolean successfulConnect;
        do {
            try {
                successfulConnect = true;
                session = jsch.getSession(sFTPUser, sFTPHost, sFTPPort);
                LOG.debug("session connected ...");

                session.setPassword(sFTPPwd);
                Properties config = new Properties();
                config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                session.setConfig(config);

                session.connect();
                LOG.debug("Sftp Session connected ...");

                channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
                LOG.debug("Sftp Channel opened ...");

                channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
                channelSftp.connect();
                LOG.info(" Sftp channel opened and connected ...");

                channelSftp.put(sourceLocation, destinationLocation);

                fileList = channelSftp.ls(destinationLocation);

            } catch (JSchException e) {
                ++attempts;
                successfulConnect = false;
                LOG.error(e);
            } catch (SftpException e) {
                ++attempts;
                successfulConnect = false;
                LOG.error(e);
            } finally {
                if (null != channelSftp) {
                    channelSftp.exit();
                    LOG.debug(" sftp Channel exited.");
                }

                if (null != channel) {
                    channel.disconnect();
                    LOG.debug(" Channel disconnected.");
                }

                if (null != session) {
                    session.disconnect();
                    LOG.debug(" Host Session disconnected.");
                }
            }
        } while (attempts < 5 && successfulConnect == false);

        fileUploadValidation(fileList, uploadedFileName);

        LOG.info("Exiting from method - uploadFileMFT ...");
    }
```

Finally uploaded file can be validated:

```
private void fileUploadValidation (Vector<String> fileList, String uploadedFileName){
        boolean isFileExistis = false;
        Object[] objArr = fileList.toArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
            String fileName = objArr[i].toString();
            isFileExistis = fileName.contains(uploadedFileName);
            if (isFileExistis) {
                LOG.info("Uploaded file '" + uploadedFileName + "' was transferred successfull ...");
                break;
            }else if(i >= objArr.length){
                LOG.info("Uploaded file '" + uploadedFileName + "' was failed to transfer ...");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please. This is not an answer. If you want to add something to your question, you should use "edit" button.

Comment: @Jauje @ Karl-Bjørnar Øie Can you please let me know what is wrong with my posted answer? If you have better answer then please feel free to add your answer. I will tick your answer if it best fit to the posted question.